field with array returns error if validation has FileSystemStoredFile[] and works fine when FileSystemStoredFile
the below code works perfectly fine:
@MaxFileSize(10e6, { each: true }) // ** 10 MB limit
  @HasExtension(['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'], MetaSource.bufferMagicNumber, {
    each: true,
  })
  @HasMimeType(['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/jpg'], { each: true })
  @IsFiles({ message: 'areaPhotos must only contain files' })
  @IsNotEmpty()
  areaPhotos: FileSystemStoredFile; 

but when i change areaPhotos from areaPhotos: FileSystemStoredFile; to areaPhotos: FileSystemStoredFile[]; making sure typescript knows it is an array of files, it fails.
in this function
    function isFile(value) {
        console.log(" ~ isFile ~ value:", value)
        console.log(" ~ isFile ~ value:", value && value instanceof StoredFile_1.StoredFile)

    return value && value instanceof StoredFile_1.StoredFile;
}

in the library code i have seen that value looks like this
 ~ isFile ~ value: [
originalName: 'Screenshot from 2024-06-11 09-44-16.png',
encoding: '7bit',
busBoyMimeType: 'image/png',
path: '/home/jamal/projects/rx-trade-backend/uploads/Screenshot from 2024-06-11 09-44-16-a5fd66.png',
size: 320685,
fileType: { ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png' }
]

which causes the validation to fail.
